# Splitting text at punctuation for all files in a directory

Tags: command-line, python, files

I need a help. I found code on this site about reading all files from directory. But this code doesn't separate the text into words by punctuation. Could you elaborate this, please?

```
import sys
import glob
import errno

path = '/Users/Юля/Desktop/practice/*.txt'   
files = glob.glob(path)   
for name in files: # 'file' is a builtin type, 'name' is a less-ambiguous variable name.
    try:
        with open(name) as f: # No need to specify 'r': this is the default.
            sys.stdout.write(f.read())
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
            raise # Propagate other kinds of IOError.
```

Comment: ...is that python? Maybe your question will get more attention on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: This code is basically a python version of `cat /Users/Юля/Desktop/practice/*.txt`. Can you provide example of what you actually need ? From what I see so far, you're asking to read each file and break words onto separate lines using punctuation characters as separators. Is that right ? Please explain

Comment: I asking to read each file and break texts onto separate words using punctuation characters as separators

Comment: To do that, you would need to read each line, with for loop ` for line in f:`, and then using `re` module do `re.split()` with  `[^\P{P}-]+` as pattern. I'd post an answer, but I am on phone, so cannot do that right now

Comment: I used your hint, but it doesn't work :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [answer by Abhijit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20570895/3701431) on the related question over at stackoverflow, one can use `punctuation` class from `string` module and use it as pattern within `re.sub()` function.

The `glob` module isn't particularly necessary, as you can take advantage of globing on command line, and slightly shorten the code.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys,re
from string import punctuation
for name in sys.argv[1:]: 
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            l = re.sub( '[{}]'.format(punctuation), '\n', line.strip()   )
            print(l)
```

With `input.txt` file like this:

```
Foo, bar !
Baz, foobar.
alpha: beta ?
```

The script works as so:

```
$ ./split_words.py  input.txt
Foo
 bar 

Baz
 foobar

alpha
 beta
```